# Having trouble calling a boolean method into another class

Tags: java

I'm having trouble calling a boolean method into another class. Whatever I try, either the program can't find the variable, or warns me about trying to use a non-static variable in a static context.

The boolean code I am trying to access

```
public boolean isSame(String title, String author)
{
    return this.title.equals(title) &&
           this.author.equals(author);
}
```

The (current) code I'm using to access the method (I know it's wrong)

```
public void copyCount(String title, String author)
{
    int numberOfCopy = 0;
    boolean Book.isSame = false;
        if(isSame == true) {
            numberOfCopy++;
        }  
    System.out.println(copyCount);
}
```

Essentially, the copyCount method (from the 'Library' class) is supposed to take 2 String parameters and test them using the isSame method (from the 'Book' class). isSame returns true if the books details match the given ones, and false if they do not.

How do I properly reference the isSame method from another class? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I properly reference the isSame method from another class?

It looks like you need an instance of the `Book` class...

```
Book book = new Book("myTitle", "myAuthor");  // I'm just guessing there's a constructor like this
boolean same = book.isSame("anotherTitle", "anotherAuthor");
// 'same' will be false
```

Comment: The only constructor I have for Book is:         

books = new ArrayList<>();

I should have mentioned that. I can't specify the book title or author as it depends on what has been created. I'm getting myself very confused as I'm using the software BlueJ which makes use of an object bench..

Comment: Do you have a `setAuthor()` and `setTitle` method on the `Book` class?  (You can use them instead of passing the author/title in the constructor.)

Comment: `public void numberOfCopies(String title, String author)
    {
        int numberOfCopy = 0;
        for(Book a: books) {
            if(isSame == true) {
                numberOfCopy++;
            }
            System.out.println(numberOfCopy);
        }
    }`

This is the code I have now, I realize now I need to compare each component of the ArrayList against the given author/title value. I don't have a setAuthor or setTitle method as these are defined within the Book constructor. However, with the current code it still doesn't find isSame as a valid variable.

Comment: I don't see anywhere (question or comments) that `isSame` is being declared as a variable -- I see it being declared as a method.  To use the method, you will always need (1) to invoke it on an instance (e.g. `myBook.isSame`) and (2) to pass the arguments (e.g. `myBook.isSame("foo", "bar")`)

Comment: Apologies, I should have said method instead of variable (very new to this). Your suggestion worked! I hadn't actually invoked the method properly. This is the portion of code I needed for it to function         `for(Book a: books) {
            if(a.isSame(title, author) == true) {` it works exactly as intended now. Thanks so much! I wanted to hit my head against a wall, I'm sure it gets worse from here..!

Answer (score 0):

**If your both methods are in different classes.**

You can only access the static method without creating the object of the class. If your isSame method is static then you can access is by using the Book.isSame(), but if your isSame method is not static then you need to create a object of Book class and then access the isSame method using that object.

See the code below:

```
Book book = new Book();
boolean result = book.isSame("title","author");
```

Pass the variables in constructor if you have. By the way the code is just a example to show the flow.

Comment: I can't make an object of the Book class because the code needs to function for any object that is created. I should specify, that this code makes use of an ArrayList (books = new ArrayList<>();)

Answer (score 0):

Earlier answers may be correct *by the requirements*, but what this sounds like is the need for an `equals` method.

By convention, Java objects all have an `equals` method, and it should be overridden when you wish to determine the equality of two objects.  Here, since you're attaching `String`s to equality, it can be tougher to infer that equality is what you were really looking for.

Here's an example:

```
public boolean equals(Book other) {
    return null != other && this.title.equals(other.title) &&
       this.author.equals(other.author);
}
```

You'd need to modify your `copyCount` method to take an instance of `Book` instead of `author` and `title`, but it'd be an overall better design.